# How to test ItemsControl with TestStack.White.UIItems

Tags: wpf, ui-testing, white-framework

So I'm trying to test UI WPF application. I'm using TestStack.White framework for testing. UI has custom control DragDropItemsControl. This control inherits from ItemsControl. So how can I test this control.

```
<wpf:DragDropItemsControl x:Name="uiTabsMinimizedList"
                                      Margin="0 0 0 5"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                      AllowDropOnItem="False"
                                      DragDropTemplate="{StaticResource TemplateForDrag}"
                                      ItemDropped="uiTabsMinimizedList_ItemDropped"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=uiMain,
                                                            Path=MinimizedTabs}"
                                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                      TextBlock.Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                                                    AncestorType=UserControl},
                                                                     Path=Foreground}">
                <wpf:DragDropItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border >
                            <TextBlock Cursor="Hand" Text="{Binding Panel.Label}" />
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </wpf:DragDropItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </wpf:DragDropItemsControl>
```

Can we test?

Comment: Are you asking how you can give each item in the set an individual Name/AutomationId?

Comment: @LordWilmore Yes. I did not find any solution  get each item from ItemsControl

Comment: So you need to set the automationproperties.automationid to something unique.  So pick a suitable string, and add a prefix that binds to something within the object that is unique, e.g. an ID.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own `AutomationPeer` for your `DragDropItemsControl` and for your custom control item then you will be able to define the AutomationId as an identifier of the your item object.

```
public class DragDropItemsControl : ItemsControl
{
    protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
    {
        return new DragDropItemsAutomationPeer(this);
    }
}
```

The custom `AutomationPeer` class for your control.

```
public class DragDropItemsControlAutomationPeer : ItemsControlAutomationPeer
{
    public DragDropItemsControlAutomationPeer(DragDropItemsControl owner)
        : base(owner)
    {
    }

    protected override string GetClassNameCore()
    {
        return "DragDropItemsControl";
    }

    protected override ItemAutomationPeer CreateItemAutomationPeer(object item)
    {
        return new DragDropItemsControlItemAutomationPeer(item, this);
    }
}
```

The custom `AutomationPeer` class for your control items.
The important part here is the implementation of the method `GetAutomationIdCore()`.

```
public class DragDropItemsControlItemAutomationPeer : ItemAutomationPeer
{
    public DragDropItemsControlItemAutomationPeer(object item, ItemsControlAutomationPeer itemsControlAutomationPeer)
        : base(item, itemsControlAutomationPeer)
    {
    }

    protected override string GetClassNameCore()
    {
        return "DragDropItemsControl_Item";
    }

    protected override string GetAutomationIdCore()
    {
        return (base.Item as MyTestItemObject)?.ItemId;
    }

    protected override AutomationControlType GetAutomationControlTypeCore()
    {
        return base.GetAutomationControlType();
    }
}
```

For the following xaml  code

```
<local:MyItemsControl x:Name="icTodoList" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="TestItemsControl">
    <local:MyItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border >
                <TextBlock Cursor="Hand" Text="{Binding Title}" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:MyItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</local:MyItemsControl>
```

Init in code behind

```
public MyMainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    List<MyTestItemObject> items = new List<MyTestItemObject>();
    items.Add(new MyTestItemObject() { Title = "Learning TestStack.White", ItemId="007" });
    items.Add(new MyTestItemObject() { Title = "Improve my english", ItemId = "008" });
    items.Add(new MyTestItemObject() { Title = "Work it out", ItemId = "009" });

    icTodoList.ItemsSource = items;
}
public class MyTestItemObject
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
}
```

We can see in UIAVerify

[image: UIAVerify screen]

Sample code to check the values

```
// retrieve the custom control
IUIItem theItemsControl = window.Get(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("008"));

if (theItemsControl is CustomUIItem)
{
    // retrieve the custom control container
    IUIItemContainer controlContainer = (theItemsControl as CustomUIItem).AsContainer();

    // get the child components
    WPFLabel theTextBlock = controlContainer.Get<WPFLabel>(SearchCriteria.Indexed(0));

    // get the text value
    string textValue = theTextBlock.Text;
}
```